# Why is my Django URL Dispatcher not working?

Tags: python, django, url, dispatcher

I'm really confused as to why my URL dispatcher is not matching this url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/2011/jun/26/third-entry/
```

This is what my main url dispatcher looks like

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^blog/', include('djangoblog.blog.urls')),
)
```

And inside my blog folder I have another url dispatcher

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
    #regex is passed to object_detail which is the name of the generic view that will pull out a single entry
    (r'^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-w]+)/$', 'object_detail', dict(info_dict, slug_field='slug',template_name='blog/detail.html')),
)
```

I also tried this url with no luck

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2011/jun/26/third-entry/
```

I must be missing something really simple...

Comment: "Django URL Dispatcher" is not a question. So please edit your question's subject to be a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexp is wrong.

`(?P<year>d{4})` should be `(?P<year>\d{4})`

The same applies to the other parts of the URI:

- `(?P<day>\d{1,2})`
- `(?P<slug>[-\w]+)`

Comment: Also, always include `/blog/` in your URL since the URLs are being dispatched from that app! :)